# Non-Blocking Thread-Safe Counter for JavaFX

Tags: multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I am trying to implement a thread-safe solution to keep a count of successful tasks that have been completed, which will ultimately get bound to label displayed on the UI. However, when I use the AtomicInteger below it locks up my UI when the tasks start running, however, if I remove all AtomicInteger refs everything works fine. Is there a non-blocking, thread-safe way which this can be accomplished?

```
public void handleSomeButtonClick(){
    if(!dataModel.getSomeList().isEmpty()) {
        boolean unlimited = false;
        int count = 0;
        AtomicInteger successCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

        if(countSelector.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Unlimited"))
            unlimited = true;
        else
            count = Integer.parseInt(countSelector.getValue());

        while(unlimited || successCount.get() < count) {
            Task task = getSomeTask();
            taskExecutor.submit(task);
            task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                if (task.getValue())
                    log.info("Successfully Completed Task | Total Count: " + successCount.incrementAndGet());
                else
                    log.error("Failed task");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955550/remove-tableview-entries-when-status-change) program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop waits for a certain number of tasks to be completed. It may even be an infinite loop.

This is not a good idea:

- You block the calling thread which seems to be the JavaFX application thread.
- You don't have any control of how many tasks are submitted. `count` could be 3, but since you only schedule the tasks in the loop, 1000 or more tasks could be created&scheduled before the first one completes.

Furthermore if you use `onSucceeded`/`onFailed`, you don't need to use `AtomicInteger` or any similar kind of synchronisation, since those handlers all run on the JavaFX application thread.

Your code could be rewritten like this:

```
private int successCount;

private void scheduleTask(final boolean unlimited) {
    Task task = getSomeTask();
    task.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
        // cannot get a Boolean from a raw task, so I assume the task is successfull iff no exception happens
        successCount++;
        log.info("Successfully Completed Task | Total Count: " + successCount);
        if (unlimited) {
            // submit new task, if the number of tasks is unlimited
            scheduleTask(true);
        }
    });
    // submit new task on failure
    task.setOnFailed(evt -> scheduleTask(unlimited));
    taskExecutor.submit(task);
}

public void handleSomeButtonClick() {
    if(!dataModel.getSomeList().isEmpty()) {
        successCount = 0;
        final boolean unlimited;
        final int count;

        if(countSelector.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Unlimited")) {
            unlimited = true;
            count = 4; // set limit of number of tasks submitted to the executor at the same time
        } else {
            count = Integer.parseInt(countSelector.getValue());
            unlimited = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            scheduleTask(unlimited);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** This code runs the risk of `handleButtonClick` being clicked multiple times before the previous tasks have been completed. You should either prevent scheduling new tasks before the old ones are completed or use some reference type containing an `int` instead for the count, create this object in `handleSomeButtonClick` and pass this object to `scheduleTask`.

Comment: This was definitely the solution, I ended up going through a few implementations and ultimately realized the point you were hammering across about submitting an infinite amount of tasks when I started getting out of memory errors. I am curious though, are there any other ways for handling these types of scenarios (limiting the number of Tasks that can be submitted to an executor based on the max pool size?)

Answer (score 0):

Your UI lock up means you do the counting(successCount.get() < count) in your FX application thread. I cannot understand why you keep submit the task in the while loop,
which one do you want to do? (1) start X(e.g. 10) task and count how many task is success. or (2) just keep starting new task and see the count go up.

if(2) then run the whole while loop in a background thread, update the UI in a Platform->runlater().

if(1) use the Future / CompletableFuture, or more powerful version Future in 3rd party package like vavr.

Comment: I want to start n amount of tasks and track the successful ones. The user has an option to select between a number or unlimited ... so I need to be able to keep a count of how many successful tasks have been completed to know when to stop submitting tasks. I tried to use the Future / Completable future before this solution but ran into the same situation beause the future.get() was blocking the Application thread as well. However, maybe I can just create a singleton void task to run the while loop Task(s) as you mentioned and just use the Atomic integer and update the ui there

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is future.get() block and wait for result.
This will be simple if you use Vavr library.
Because it can attach a code to its future which run automatically when success or fail.
So you don't have to wait.
Here is a example which using Vavr's future.

```
        CheckedFunction0<String> thisIsATask = () -> {
        if ( /*do something*/ ){
            throw new Exception("Hey");
        }
        return "ABC";
    };

    List<Future<String>> futureList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        futureList.add(Future.of(getExecutorService(), thisIsATask));
    }

    futureList.forEach((task) -> {
        // This will run if success
        task.onSuccess(s -> s.equals("ABC") ? Platform.runLater(()->UpdateCounter()) : wtf());
        // Your get the exception if it is fail;
        task.onFailure(e -> e.printStackTrace());
        // task.onComplete() will run on any case when complete
    });
```

This is not blocking, the code at onSucess onFailure or onComplete will run when the task is finish or an exception is catch.

Note: Future.of will use the executorService you pass in to run each task at new thread, the code you provide at onSuccess will continue to run at that thread once the task is done so if you calling javafx remember the Platform.runLater()

Also if you want to run something when all task is finish, then

```
    // the code at onComplete will run when tasks all done
    Future<Seq<String>> all = Future.sequence(futureList);
    all.onComplete((i) -> this.btnXYZ.setDisable(false));
```