# Binding for userdata change of nodes inside a list?

Tags: java, javafx, observable

I'm building a JavaFX application where I have a GridPane of 10 labels, and the user can assign objects to these labels per drag and drop. I used the userdata property of nodes, so when the user drops an object onto one label, it sets that object as userdata of this label.

Now I want to set a bind for the disableProperty of a button, so that the button only gets enabled when the user "filled" all of these labels with data. I've tried several things, finally I came to something like this:

```java
FilteredList<Node> emptySlots = gridPane.getChildren().filtered(node -> node.getUserData() == null);
SimpleListProperty<Node> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>(emptySlots);
BooleanProperty hasEmptySlots = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
hasEmptySlots.bind(not(listProperty.emptyProperty()));
button.disableProperty().bind(hasEmptySlots);
```

But sadly the emptySlots list doesn't seem to update when the userdata property of the labels gets changed. I already tried to find ways to update this list, but I only find ways that involve ObservableLists with own classes and custom setup when the list is created like this ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955550/remove-tableview-entries-when-status-change)):

```
ObservableList<Model> masterData = FXCollections.observableArrayList<>(model ->
    new Observable[]{model.statusProperty()});
```

But I don't have that option here.

Has anyone an idea how to archieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [an extractor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)) could have worked using [a mirror](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent(java.util.List,javafx.collections.ObservableList)) of the `children` list, but unfortunately the `userData` is not stored in a property (i.e. it's not `Observable`). To do what you want you'll have to use a different mechanism to store your user's objects.

An alternative to using the `userData`, in the same spirit of your current approach, is to use a `Node`'s [properties](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#getProperties()). These properties are stored in an `ObservableMap<Object, Object>` which means they can be observed for changes. To use this option you'll still want to use an extractor and mirror the `children` list.

```
class Foo {

    private static final String USER_OBJECT_KEY = "USER_OBJECT";

    private final GridPane gridPane = ...;
    private final Button button = ...;

    Foo() {
        ObservableList<Node> mirror = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                n -> new Observable[]{n.getProperties()}
        );
        Bindings.bindContent(mirror, gridPane.getChildren());
        FilteredList<Node> filtered = mirror.filtered(
                n -> !n.getProperties().containsKey(USER_OBJECT_KEY)
        );
        button.disableProperty(Bindings.isEmpty(filtered));
    }

}
```

The above uses [`Bindings.isEmpty(ObservableList)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#isEmpty(javafx.collections.ObservableList)) rather than wrapping the observable list in a `ListProperty`.

You may also want to consider moving this state out into a model. That way you avoid coupling the state of the application with JavaFX GUI objects (the model should know nothing about the view).